# JQuery-UI horizontal dragging with vertical scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, mobile, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a page full of draggable divs only in horizontal (on axis X).

When I'm in a touch device I can't scroll down the page, due conflicts between scroll and drag.

Here's a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/742cX/10/) (test in touch devices and try to scroll).

My draggable code:

```
 $(".cell").draggable({
    axis: "x",
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        var size = $(".cell").width();

        if (ui.offset.left > size - em(4)) {
            ui.position.left = size - em(4);
        }
    },
    start: function (event, ui) {
        if (initialPosition == null) {
            initialPosition = ui.position.left;
        }

        $(".cell").not(ui.helper).each(function () {
            var pos = $(this).position().left;
            if (pos > 0) {
                $(this).animate({
                    left: initialPosition
                }, 200, null);
            }
        });
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        var size = $(".cell").width();
        if (ui.position.left > initialPosition) {
            if (ui.position.left - initialPosition >= size / 3) {
                ui.helper.animate({
                    left: size - em(4)
                }, 200, null);
            } else {
                ui.helper.animate({
                    left: initialPosition
                }, 200, null);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I want to detect if the user is scrolling vertically before start dragging and cancel the 
horizontal dragging.

Help me, please. How can I make this work?

Comment: I would suggest to use floating button to move up and down.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem similar to this one and eventually found a fairly simple solution.

In my scenario I had an inbox list whose items that you could drag to the left or right to expose action buttons. The entire inbox item must be draggable -- so the use of a drag handle was not an option.

jQuery's `draggable` prevents vertical scrolling on touch screens if the touch was initiated inside a `draggable` element. So if the screen was filled with draggable inbox items, then the user would become trapped -- unable to scroll up or down.

The solution that worked for me was to measure any change in the cursor's vertical position and use `window.scrollBy` to manually scroll the window by the same amount:

```
var firstY = null;      
var lastY = null;
var currentY = null;
var vertScroll = false;
var initAdjustment = 0;

// record the initial position of the cursor on start of the touch
jqDraggableItem.on("touchstart", function(event) {
    lastY = currentY = firstY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
});

// fires whenever the cursor moves
jqDraggableItem.on("touchmove", function(event) {
    currentY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
    var adjustment = lastY-currentY;

    // Mimic native vertical scrolling where scrolling only starts after the
    // cursor has moved up or down from its original position by ~30 pixels.
    if (vertScroll == false && Math.abs(currentY-firstY) > 30) {
        vertScroll = true;
        initAdjustment = currentY-firstY;
    }

    // only apply the adjustment if the user has met the threshold for vertical scrolling
    if (vertScroll == true) {
        window.scrollBy(0,adjustment + initAdjustment);
        lastY = currentY + adjustment;
    }

});

// when the user lifts their finger, they will again need to meet the 
// threshold before vertical scrolling starts.
jqDraggableItem.on("touchend", function(event) {
    vertScroll = false;
});
```

This will closely mimic native scrolling on a touch device.

Answer (score -2):

I use jquery.ui.touch-punch.js and this worked for me, line 38:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

[Reference](https://steampixel.de/enable-vertical-page-scrolling-jquery-ui-touch-punch/)

Comment: Please provide the main parts of the code in your answer. In case that in a future that link is broken your answer will be useless. Thanks